# Vim: Errors opening "tagbar" plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed the "tagbar" plugin using Vundle, by addind this to my vimrc:

```
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'
```

Version 5.8 of ctags is installed and on my path.  I'm using win7.  When I try to start tagbar, however, I get this (note: I'm editing a ruby file and executed `:TagbarToggle`:

[image: tagbar errors]

Comment: I would check under `~/.vim/bundle/` to be sure that all of the plugin’s files made it in, and also maybe run `:scriptnames` to see whether they are all being sourced. This would make sense if `plugin/tagbar.vim` wasn’t being sourced.

Comment: Yeah, I restarted vim and re-ran the :BundleInstall, and now it's working.  Should have tried that before.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check after listing the `Bundle` to be sure that all of its files were pulled down by Vundle — `~/.vim/bundle/tagbar/` should exist, and

```
ls ~/.vim/bundle/tagbar/
```

should list all of the plugin’s files and directories (`autoload/`, `doc/`, `plugin/`, etc.). (Vundle should do this when `:BundleInstall` — or `:BundleInstall!`, which updates listed plugins — is run.)

If all of the plugin’s files are there, try running `:scriptnames` to see whether they’re all being sourced.